# @MapKeyJoinColumn table attribute usage

Tags: java, annotations, jpa-2.0

I'm working on a JPA Compliancy Kit for my internship, and part of that is testing for proper implementation of corner cases.

I looked at @MapKeyJoinColumn today.

Meet its table attribute:

> String table - (Optional) The name of the table that contains the foreign key column. 
>       If the join is for a map key for an element collection, the foreign key column is in the collection table for the map value. 
>       If the join is for a map key for a ManyToMany entity relationship or for a OneToMany entity relationship using a join table, the foreign key column is in a join table. 
>       If the join is for a OneToMany entity relationship using a foreign key mapping strategy, the foreign key column for the map key is in the table of the entity that is the value of the map.

With as default value:

> If the map is for an element collection, the name of the collection table for the map value.
>       If the map is for a OneToMany or ManyToMany entity relationship using a join table, the name of the join table for the map.
>       If the map is for a OneToMany entity relationship using a foreign key mapping strategy, the name of the primary table of the entity that is the value of the map.

(I typed that by hand, probably shouldn't have done that.)

---

My question:
Why does this attribute exist? Is there any case in which it would be different than whatever it defaults to - is it a "for future usage"?

Correction - Is there any case in which it would be different than whatever it defaults to, **without being semantically wrong**?